# How to find an element by the variable title using Selenium and Python

Tags: python, selenium, xpath, css-selectors, xpath-1.0

Building a scraper with selenium in python. Trying to select a number of buttons in sequence that have sequential titles of the form 'Race n' where n is an integer.

I want to be able to do something like:

```
driver.find_element_by_css_selector("a[title*=race_i]").click()
```

where the variable `race_i = 'Race ' + str(i)`

Is it possible to feed the css or xpath lookup a variable, rather than a plain string? The number of buttons varies so I need this function to be adaptable and work for any value of n.

Comment: Welcome to SO. You can append the variable as follows. `driver.find_element_by_css_selector("a[title*=Race" + str(i) + "]").click()`

Answer (score 0):

How about you just concat the variable to the xpath/css selector?

```
driver.find_element_by_css_selector("a[title*=" + race_i + "]").click()
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `format` function such as

```
for i in range(1,10):
 driver.find_element_by_css_selector("a[title*=race_{}]".format(i)).click()
```

Answer (score 0):

To find an element through the variable `title` you can use either of the following [Locator Strategies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48369043/official-locator-strategies-for-the-webdriver/48376890#48376890):

- `css_selector`:

  ```
  for i in range(1,5):
      driver.find_element_by_css_selector("a[title*='race_'"+ str(i) +"]").click()
  ```
- `xpath`:

  ```
  for i in range(1,5):
      driver.find_element_by_xpath('//a[contains(@title, "race_{}")]'.format(i)).click()
  ```